# Algorithm for detecting contiguous pixels of the same colo(u)r to generate an image map

Tags: algorithm, imagemap

I want to code an app which will take an image and recognize the constituent parts and generate an [image map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_map).

Imagine an image containing a map of the USA (ignroe for now whetehr it is SVG, JPEG, PNG, etc).

If I reserve 3 RGB values for borders between states, state names printed on the map and the non-map stuff at the edges (because the image is rectangular and the USA is not), I want to recognize each of the states and generate an image map where I Can assign JS handler to a click on each state.

Alas, I don't know where to start with the algorithm. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the work: [Flood Fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill)

Comment: Looks good (+1), but it doesn't really help me to find the outline of the shapes; not without a ***LOT*** of work. And I still don''t really see the algorithm that I need

Comment: For each region (state in your case) you will have one flood fill process, so pipeline will look something like this:

Comment: For each region(state in your case) you will have one floodFill process, so pipeline will look something like this: 1. Find first non processed px 2. Perform floodFill 3. Repeat 1. and 2. until there is no unprocessed pxls. I will continue in next comment...

Comment: In flood fill procedure when you check if N, W, S and E pixels are in target color, if some is not then you should also check if that pixel is in border color. So if some of them is not target color AND it's in border color then proclaime that pixel for border pixel, and add it  to set of border pixels. Let floodFill procedure returns that set. With that after each flood fill you will also have region outline pixels. This is much easier to achieve using  queue-based implementattion than recursive implementation.

Comment: I see now, thanks. But you spoiled it for me because I like recursion :-)  Of course, this method probably means that I will include every pixel of the border into the image map. Think of a square - it only needs 4 pairs of coordinates, but I will end up with one pair for every pixel of the border. Maybe I can process it afterwards; put all the cords into a list, then run along the list and if difference is only one pixel and the one after is also the same difference in the same direction, then delete this pixel.